# Custom Footer view in UITableView is not visible after section is deleted and then inserted again

Tags: ios, uitableview, footer

iOS 13.5/14, XCode 12
UITableView displays section and custom footer.
In commit editingStyle, the section is deleted all, works well.
Insert a new row into the model, trigger reloadData, the section appears with new row, the footer of the section is of the correct height to accommodate custom view. However, the view is not visible.

Verified: can see the view in the Debug View Hierarchy it is the top view
Verified: viewForFooterInSection return view
Verified: heightForFooterInSection is correct
Verified: isHidden is false

the only thing that works is forcing reload of the section. Anyone with any suggestions?

attempted to force layoutIfNeeded setNeedsDisplay can't understand what is going on

Comment: You need to look at what your code is doing differently between initial load and reload. Without posting any code, pretty tough to offer any other help.